# How to get an integer o/p of a func. in a between stmt of aggregation by partition between preceding and current row in sql server mgmt studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want the user to input a number, say 4 which gives a number 47 after going through a formula. Then this 47 sets itself as preceding row in the sql statement.

The function

```
 use Tableau;
 DROP FUNCTION dbo.getyrs;
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getyrs(@parm Integer)
 RETURNS INTEGER
 AS
 BEGIN
RETURN @parm
 END;
```

Here i created a dummy table to store the calculated value (Since i could not do the calculation in the function, got an error called "cannot convert * to integer)

```
 select distinct dbo.getyrs(4)*12 as abc from [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table1$];
```

And here is where i want to put it finally

```
select  
 avg(x.[Real_MSCI_Earnings_idx]) over(partition by [Country] order by [Date], date rows between "HERE" preceding and current row) as rolling_avg_4,
from
mytable x
```

That "HERE" needs to be 47

I tried putting it as an extra column but was unable to do so. This is what I tried

```
ALTER TABLE Tableau.dbo.Country_table2$
ADD EXTRA integer;

UPDATE Tableau.dbo.Country_table2$
Set EXTRA = (select distinct dbo.getyrs(4)*12-1 as abc from [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table1$]);
```

then i did this

```
avg(x.[Real_MSCI_Earnings_idx]) over(partition by [Country] order by [Date], date rows between x.EXTRA preceding and current row) as rolling_avg_4,
```

But this is wrong.
Can anyone suggest any way?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio